# Is it haram to dab in Fortnite?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, sin

I know it's not good to dab as muslim, but what about in the videogame Fortnite? I want to ask this question because lately I have been feeling guilty about dancing in Fortnite, especially when I dab.

Comment: Could you explain to why it would be okay or wrong?

Comment: Because I know that dancing is haram in islam, and when I do the "dab" in Fornite I dance.

Answer (score 0):

The Islamic ruling on Dabbing (Haram) remains the same irrespective of its origin. Whether it originates from drug users, music industry, hip hop, sports stars or Satanism. So yes it is this is like saying is it haram to kill in video games playing fortnite in general is haram you are killing to win.

Comment: okay, good to know!